# Suggestions of books more complex than Spivak and Apostol for Calculus 1?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I've been using Apostol and reusing until got satisfied, I've done the same with Spivak, and I wan't to take another level now.

Comment: As a student, or as a teacher?

Comment: Is there difference?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want another level, why seek a calculus book? Get something on real and/or complex analysis, or functional analysis, for instance:

- Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis
- Stein & Shakarchi, [Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691113866) and [Complex Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691113858)
- Yeh, [Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814578541)

You should clarify the expected level, and the goal: self learning? Follow a course (then lookup the recommended reading)?

---

*Answer to the comment below*

You can't go too far. I asked the goal because I see (mainly) two possible situations:

- You want to improve grades for your current calculus class. Then it's ok to stick with calculus material, but it's also a good idea to read material from 1 or 2 years ahead (not more), to see where what you are currently learning is leading, and to get a better understanding of the "landscape". I would recommend this, especially if you are comfortable with your current courses.
- You want to learn on your own. Then the only limit is your capacity to digest new and difficult stuff. Good books help (IMO, Yeh is great for self learning, Rudin not so much). And you can choose whatever you like, so it can't be wrong to learn advanced stuff in analysis if you like it.

What's the goal? Do you plan to study mathematics at an advanced level, and to prepare now for the next level, or (for instance) to turn to applied maths and engineering? Or something else?

Comment: You are right, the problem is that im afraid of going to far in analysis, i dont want to be so fixed in this. But i will try, maybe i m prejudiced with this branch of math.

Comment: @Jordan I updated the answer to take your comment into account. I really depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Its only by my own, i just want learn everything i can about calculus and see the most complex thing possible,I'm studying engineering, but its totally boring. But I just want it to learn how the world works. How can I express myself better: i want to understand how math works in the minors details, but a i don't want to lead with these details, proving everything every time

Comment: I see. Go ahead!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps that Jean Dieudonné's *Foundations of Modern Analysis* would be appropriate.